# Is there a nice shortcut way to export oracle into hssql?

Tags: oracle, reverse-engineering, hsqldb

I'm dealing with a legacy database and I'd like to create a test version of it.

It's based  on views as opposed to tables.

I'm wondering if someone here knows a nice quick way to export sql from the views with all the data types which I could then use to create a hsql table based version of the  database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use most IDEs (Toad or [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) for example) to view and extract underlying SQL from views (and types from snapshot tables).  This would be the easiest and most friendly approach.

The alternative would be to use a built in package DBMS_METADATA

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'MY_VIEW') from dual;
```

See [here](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_metadata.html) for other options (like 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW') and examples.

Comment: actually I can get the view description, but to get the data types out as well is what I'm really looking for. A shortcut to convert it to a table representation in hssql for testing like

Comment: well, you'd get the type detail from the underlying tables of the view.  If you have a test db, u can create a materialized view with same SQL and then extract the snapshot table's DDL (create materialized view MY_MV ... as select ... where 1=0);  The last part (where 1=0) will make it fast and empty.